# Populating a view in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

Pardon the long explanation.  I hope this makes sense:

I am trying to create a view that contains a certain content type that does not contain taxonomy terms of a certain list.  The structure goes like this:

```
A project is the main container of all SKUs that exist
Inside each project are pages.
Inside each page are callouts.
Inside the callouts are the SKUs.

In other words:   PROJECT > PAGE > CALLOUT > SKU
```

I am currently able to populate ALL SKUs that don't have the terms as so:

[image: Populate All SKUs]

I need to limit this to certain projects.  My guess is that I need to use Argument and Relationships, but I'm unsure of how to go about this deep of a hierarchy.

My guess is that I need to create Relationships of PROJECTS and PAGES, and an Argument of PROJECT.

Any help would be awesome.  Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

If your url is something like `/projectid/pageid/calloutid/skuid`, you may want to use arguments and `%1` to use the `projectid`, `%2` for `pageid` etc and then put your restriction of pages or whatever arguments to restrict sku's for certain pages.

Comment: The issue is that this is a project wide instance.  In other words, they won't want to go from page to page to page to locate all the information.  Populate based on the entire project.

Comment: I was able to complete this using a custom module, and just returning the value.  I was already using the module for something related, so I just looped it in.